# Create X Axis from row in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot the x-axis from the top row of my dataframe, and the y-axis from another row in my dataframe.
My dataframe looks like this:

sector_data =

```
Time    13:00   13:15   13:30   13:45
Utilities   1235654 1456267 1354894 1423124
Transports  506245  554862  534685  524962
Telecomms   142653  153264  162357  154698
```

I've tried a lot of different things, with this seeming to make the most sense. But nothing works:

```
sector_data.plot(kind='line',x='Time',y='Utilities')
plt.show()
```

I keep getting: 
KeyError: 'Time'

It should end up looking like this:

[Expected Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gS6YA.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mpxkl.jpg)

Comment: Pandas plotting function takes the columns as input, not the rows. You can transpose your dataframe.

Comment: if ```['Time',Utilities','Transports','Telecomms']``` are the index then you can use matplotlib to plot. ```plt.plot(df.loc['Time'].values,df.loc['Utilities'].values)```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the little information you provide I believe this should help:

```
df = sector_data.T
df.plot(kind='line',x='Time',y='Utilities')
plt.show()
```

This is how I made a case example (I have already transposed the dataframe)

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
a = {'Time':['13:00','13:15','13:30','13:45'],'Utilities':[1235654,1456267,1354894,1423124],'Transports':[506245,554862,534685,524962],'Telecomms':[142653,153264,162357,154698]}
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
df.plot(kind='line',x='Time',y='Utilities')
plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help! I've added your script verbatim but I still don't get the time as the x axis. It's blank.

Comment: I"m trying to add a picture but can't figure out how in this comment.

Comment: Do you mind editing your answer with what your dataframe looks like *after* applying the transpose? that is, after `df=sector_data.T` that should help me understand why isn't time as the x-axis

Comment: Telecomms   Time  Transports  Utilities
0     142653  13:00      506245    1235654
1     153264  13:15      554862    1456267
2     162357  13:30      534685    1354894
3     154698  13:45      524962    1423124

Answer (score 0):

Let's take an example DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
 df = pd.DataFrame({'ColA':['Time','Utilities','Transports','Telecomms'],'ColB':['13:00', 1235654, 506245, 142653],'ColC':['14:00', 1234654, 506145, 142650], 'ColD':['15:00', 4235654, 906245, 142053],'ColE':['16:00', 4205654, 906845, 742053]})
df = df.set_index('ColA') #set index for the column A or the values you want to plot for
```

Now you can easily plot with matplotlib

```
plt.plot(df.loc['Time'].values,df.loc['Utilities'].values)
```

[image]

Comment: TREMENDOUS! Thank you very much.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it solved your problem. Thanks!